# Can not find path:'/root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top_ecc'

Tags: ssl, http

I renew the ssl certificate using acme.sh and store in folder like this:

```
[Sun Mar  3 11:36:44 CST 2024] Your cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top/*.poemhub.top.cer
[Sun Mar  3 11:36:44 CST 2024] Your cert key is in: /root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top/*.poemhub.top.key
[Sun Mar  3 11:36:44 CST 2024] The intermediate CA cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top/ca.cer
[Sun Mar  3 11:36:44 CST 2024] And the full chain certs is there: /root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top/fullchain.cer
```

when using this command to renew the certificate:

```
/root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --renew -d "*.poemhub.top" --keylength ec-256 --force
```

but when I use this command to install, the folder name did not match, the generate folder is:

```
[Sun Mar  3 12:17:03 CST 2024] Your cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top/*.poemhub.top.cer
[Sun Mar  3 12:17:03 CST 2024] Your cert key is in: /root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top/*.poemhub.top.key
[Sun Mar  3 12:17:03 CST 2024] The intermediate CA cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top/ca.cer
[Sun Mar  3 12:17:03 CST 2024] And the full chain certs is there: /root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top/fullchain.cer
```

the loading folder is `*.poemhub.top_ecc`:

```
[root@k8sslave01 source]# /root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --install-cert -d *.poemhub.top --ecc --key-file       /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/privkey.pem  --fullchain-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/poemhub/fullchain.pem --reloadcmd     "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload"
[Sun Mar  3 11:49:05 CST 2024] The domain '*.poemhub.top' is not a cert name. You must use the cert name to specify the cert to install.
[Sun Mar  3 11:49:05 CST 2024] Can not find path:'/root/.acme.sh/*.poemhub.top_ecc'
```

what should I do to match the folder? can I just rename the folder?